# Компиляция cpp-файла с файлом предкомпиллированных заголовков расположенного в другой папке

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Как решить вопрос с ситуацией заданной в теме?

У меня есть проект на C++ структура, котого выглядит так:

```
../parse/
../../export.cpp
../../import.cpp
../../и др. файлы
../precomp.hpp
../precomp.cpp
```

В текущей ситуации получаю вполне логичную ошибку:

> \parse\export.cpp(1): warning C4627: '#include "../precomp.hpp"':
>   skipped when looking for precompiled header use
>             Add directive to 'precomp.hpp' or rebuild precompiled header

Мне бы хотелось избежать ситуации с переносом файлов из папки `parse/` на уровень выше где расположен файл `precomp.hpp`, но как иначе пока не вижу способа.

Так есть ли способ скомпиллировать проект с текущей структурой с предкомпиллированными заголовками, когда файл `precomp.hpp` в одной, а `export.cpp` в другой?

Comment: И как же компилятор должен найти этот файл если файл лежит уровнем выше?

Comment: Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ и я его отмечу как решение. Я не знаю почему, но помогло! А как будет в Linux не знаю, но это уже тема другого мозголомания :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле `\parse\export.cpp` инклюдьте без указания пути:

```
#include "precomp.hpp"
```

Не важно, что путь не существует, главное чтобы совпадало написание `precomp.hpp` с тем, которое указано в настройке `Precompiled Header File` проекта/файла.